# What is the linear functional associated with the dense subspace of polynomials in $\mathcal{C}[a,b]$?

Tags: functional-analysis

According to the [Wierstrauss Approximation Theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeierstrassApproximationTheorem.html), the set of polynomials on an interval $[a,b]$ are a dense linear subspace in $\mathcal{C}[a,b]$, the set of continuous functions with the sup norm. I am learning functional analysis. I believe this means that there must be some discontinuous linear function $L:\mathcal{C}[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ such that the set of polynomials equals the set $ \{x \vert L(x) = \alpha\}$ for some $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.

Just to get a better grip on these concepts, I'd like to know what that discontinuous linear functional $L$ "is". Is it possible to describe it in some intuitive way?

Comment: The polynomials contain $0,$ so $\alpha=0.$ The kernel of a linear functional is a linear subspace of codimension $1.$ The set of polynomials is not the subspace of codimension $1.$ Hence no such $L$ exists.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc
RE: "The kernel of a linear functional is a linear subspace of codimension 1."
I thought that is only true for continuous linear functionals, no? Isn't the set of polynomials a dense hyperplane? And doesn't that mean it is the kernel of some discontinuous linear functional? Or are some dense subspaces not hyperplanes?

Comment: It has nothing to do with continuity
Just linear algebra is involved. Let $f(x_0) =1.$ Then every element $x$ in the space can be represented as $x=[x-f(x)x_0]+f(x)x_0$. The first summand is in $\ker f,$ the second is a multiple of $x_0.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Excellent! Back to fundamentals.

Comment: What is true is that the kernel of an unbounded linear functional is a dense subspace. But not every dense subspace is of this form (only if it has codimension one).